# Can we force a type for dictionaries using boto3 TypeSerializer?

Tags: boto3

I am trying to use boto3's [TypeSerializer](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html?highlight=serializer) to force everything in my dictionary to be set as a 'string'. Right now it's deciding on what it considers a boolean, string, etc. and setting them as such.

It is unable to pick up some python booleans as 'booleans' and is setting them to null values. If I can force the serialize method to set everything as a 'string' it will make my life a whole lot easier, especially when working with our preexisting React front-end code.

Thank you!